# How to import a project into eclipse downloaded from developer.android.com zip file

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm sorry if this looks like the same question a million times...but a google search for this provides no results

I downloaded code from http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html. then i tried to import into eclipse project . But i unable to import that project into eclipse project. can any body help me to import that project into eclipse project.

Comment: I was download your project, There is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in your project explorer --> Import --> Android --> Existing android code to workspace --> click browse --> select your project folder and click finish. You are done

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Download the file.
2. Extract the zip archive.
3. In ecllipse to to File then select Import
4. Then select Android and then select Existing Android project to workspace
5. Browse to the path where you extracted the downloaded file and click finish
6. It is recommended to tick the copy to workspace dialog.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to Extract the zip file and in eclipse Right click in your project explorer --> Import --> Android --> Existing android code to workspace --> click browse --> select your project folder and click finish. That is it.