# qHD and 800x480 different layout or drawable or both

Tags: android, screen-resolution, dpi

I have an application that has a grid with 2 columns and 5 rows.
Each cell is an image and a text
The application works well on 800x480. (below image)

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/2v2v0hj.jpg]

The problem is when I run the emulator for 960x540 the grid look like this  (below image)

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/fmlg8.jpg]

Both use drawable-hdpi and layout-hdpi.

Is there any way even an unorthodox to overcome this problem ?

The code for the grid is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/IdMainCat"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<!--     Screen Design for Photos
 -->

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:paddingTop="5dp"
          android:text="@string/app_name"
          android:textColor="#ffffff"
          android:textSize="25sp" />

      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/bLang"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:src="@drawable/gc"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:background="@null"
          android:text="Button" />

      <GridView
          android:id="@+id/gridView2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
          android:columnWidth="270dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:numColumns="2"
          android:paddingTop="7dp"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

      </GridView>


  </RelativeLayout>
```

and the code for the images is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gridview_style"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="0.6"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ac" >

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image2"
        android:background="#aa000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textColor="#e0f901"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can see **many** strange things here...

Comment: ... could you make it work? Because I have some working code for you. I thought I could mke a zip an put it on your DropBox, if you share me a folder. I guess you know how to import a zipped project? The only thin notable is that for easyness (or lazyness) I incorporated **HomeAdapter** inside **Home.java**. It makes no harm, since it's only a helper for the Home GridView. And that I commented some of the original code to make mine work as a stand alone without having your other pictures, classes, font, DBHelper, strings, ...

Comment: How to import a zipped project:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19535338/2649012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see **many** anomalies in the code you posted:

`fill_parent` has been deprecated since API level 8.
Now, use `match_parent`, instead.

`weights` aren't effective in RelativeLayouts.
They only work in LinearLayouts and derivates.

`android:textSize` should always be in **sp**, not in **dp**.

This: `android:text="@+id/label"` is **totally wrong**.

TextViews, as well as ImageViews, are **clickable**.
And ImageButtons, as well as ImageViews, don't show any text.
You really don't need an ImageButton.
Therefore, to optimize (by reducing the View count), an image can be inserted in a TextView as a **compound drawable**.
Just assign you onClickListener to the TextView, instead of to the ImageButton.

So, my new version of your layout (**home_grid.xml**) would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_back"
    >
    <!-- Screen Design for Photos -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/gc"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
    />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
        android:columnWidth="270dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the **optimized** (for performance) layout (**home_mobile.xml**) for the icons is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_item2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="#a000"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ac"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fdf0"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

You can set the image in Java (**Home.java**):

```
Drawable drw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ac);
// setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
myText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (null, drw, null, null);
```

All this should work **nearly** out-of-the-box.
Just fix your Java code to match (for setting the compound drawables, the clicks, ...)
But it's really a **trivial fixing**.

**[EDIT]**

This is your fixed **Home.java** - but still the `home_mobile` layout has to be fixed...
... For that, I will need your **HomeAdapter.java** class, too.

```
package com.tg.sam;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.tg.sam.HomeAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{
    public static SharedPreferences settings = null;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "TG_LANG";
    GridView gridView = null;
    Integer[] images = {};
    String[] categories = {};
    // ** NO **
    //ImageButton lang;

    // city, accommodation, food, shopping, fun, health, pcare, pserv, ed, ph;
    TGDatabase db = null;
    Intent majorlist = null;
    RelativeLayout homelayout = null;
    Bundle bundle = null;
    TextView tv = null;

    // String[] categories = new String[] { "Accomodation" , "Food", "Beaches",
    // "Tourism" , "Health" , "Places" , "Shopping", "Real Estate"};
    /*
     * public static Home group; private ArrayList<View> history;
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        // ** THIS IS REALLY BAD!! **
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        /*
         * Toast.makeText(MajorList.this, "onConfigurationChanged(): " +
         * newConfig.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         */
        // onCreate(null);
        /*
        setContentView(R.layout.home_grid);
        //homelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.IdMainCat);
        //homelayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_back);
        */
        // homelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        cbutton();
/*      db = new TGDatabase(this);
        intialize();
        db.close();

        String fontPath = "aus.ttf";
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        categories = new String[]
        {
            getResources().getString(R.string.Lcity),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Accommodation),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Food),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Shopping),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Fun),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Health),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Pcare),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Pserv),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Education),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Phn)
        };
        images = new Integer[]
        {
            R.drawable.lc, R.drawable.ac, R.drawable.fd,
            R.drawable.sh, R.drawable.fn, R.drawable.hm, R.drawable.pc,
            R.drawable.ps, R.drawable.ed, R.drawable.pn
        };

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        gridView.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(this, categories, images));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);*/
    }

    private void cbutton() {
        String string = "";
        Drawable drw = null;
        if (settings.getString("lang", "en").equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
        {
            string="en";
            //Language_check(this, "en");
            // ** NO **
            //lang.setImageResource(R.drawable.gc);
            drw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gc);
        }
        else
        {
            //Language_check(this, "el");
            string="el";
            // ** NO **
            //lang.setImageResource(R.drawable.uk);
            drw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uk);
        }
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (null, null, drw, null);

        Locale locale2 = new Locale(string);
        Locale.setDefault(locale2);
        Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
        config2.locale = locale2;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        /*
        if(getResources().getString(R.string.locale).equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
        {
            lang.setImageResource(R.drawable.gc);
        }
        else
        {
            lang.setImageResource(R.drawable.uk);
        }
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_grid);
        // ** NO - You already set it (my update) in the layout file **
        //homelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.IdMainCat);
        //homelayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_back);
        // homelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        db = new TGDatabase(this);
        intialize();
        db.close();

        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        lbutton();

        String fontPath = "aus.ttf";
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        categories = new String[]
        {
            getResources().getString(R.string.Lcity),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Accommodation),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Food),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Shopping),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Fun),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Pcare),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Pserv),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Education),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Health),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Phn)
        };
        images = new Integer[]
        {
            R.drawable.lc,
            R.drawable.ac,
            R.drawable.fd,
            R.drawable.sh,
            R.drawable.fn,
            R.drawable.pc,
            R.drawable.ps,
            R.drawable.ed,
            R.drawable.hm,
            R.drawable.pn
        };

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        gridView.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(this, categories, images));
        gridView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        gridView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // this.history = new ArrayList<View>(); group = this;
    }

    private void lbutton()
    {
        Drawable drw = null;
        if (getResources().getString(R.string.locale).equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
        {
            // ** NO **
            //lang.setImageResource(R.drawable.gc);
            drw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gc);

            editor=settings.edit();
            editor.putString("lang", "en");
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            // ** NO **
            //lang.setImageResource(R.drawable.uk);
            drw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uk);

            editor=settings.edit();
            editor.putString("lang", "el");
            editor.commit();
        }
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (null, null, drw, null);

        /*
         * if(getResources().getString(R.string.locale).equals("en")) { // Call
         * above method with context & newLocale
         * lang.setImageResource(R.drawable.gc); }else{ // Call above method
         * with context & newLocale lang.setImageResource(R.drawable.uk); }
         */
    }

    private void intialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*
         * city = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iml); accommodation =
         * (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ima); food = (ImageButton)
         * findViewById(R.id.imfo); shopping = (ImageButton)
         * findViewById(R.id.ims); fun = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imfu);
         * health = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imh); pcare = (ImageButton)
         * findViewById(R.id.impc); pserv = (ImageButton)
         * findViewById(R.id.imps); ed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imed);
         * ph = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.impn);
         */

         // ** NO **
        //lang = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bLang);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        /*
         * city.setOnClickListener(this);
         * accommodation.setOnClickListener(this);
         * food.setOnClickListener(this); shopping.setOnClickListener(this);
         * fun.setOnClickListener(this); health.setOnClickListener(this);
         * pcare.setOnClickListener(this); pserv.setOnClickListener(this);
         * ed.setOnClickListener(this); ph.setOnClickListener(this);
         */

        // ** NO **
        //lang.setOnClickListener
        tv.setOnClickListener
        (
            new OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Check();
                }
            }
        );

    }

    /*
     * public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub switch
     * (v.getId()){ case R.id.iml: majorlist = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(),
     * MajorList.class); majorlist.putExtra("type",
     * getResources().getString(R.string.Lcity)); //startActivity(majorlist);
     * break; case R.id.ima: majorlist = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(),
     * MajorList.class); majorlist.putExtra("type",
     * getResources().getString(R.string.Accommodation));
     * //startActivity(majorlist); break; case R.id.imfo: majorlist = new
     * Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MajorList.class);
     * majorlist.putExtra("type", getResources().getString(R.string.Food));
     * //startActivity(majorlist); break; case R.id.ims: majorlist = new
     * Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MajorList.class);
     * majorlist.putExtra("type",getResources().getString(R.string.Shopping));
     * //startActivity(majorlist); break; case R.id.imfu: majorlist = new
     * Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MajorList.class);
     * majorlist.putExtra("type",getResources().getString(R.string.Fun));
     * //startActivity(majorlist); break; case R.id.imh: majorlist = new
     * Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MajorList.class);
     * majorlist.putExtra("type", getResources().getString(R.string.Health));
     * //startActivity(majorlist); break; case R.id.impc: majorlist = new
     * Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MajorList.class);
     * majorlist.putExtra("type", getResources().getString(R.string.Pcare));
     * //startActivity(majorlist); break; case R.id.imps: majorlist = new
     * Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MajorList.class);
     * majorlist.putExtra("type", getResources().getString(R.string.Pserv));
     * //startActivity(majorlist); break; case R.id.imed: majorlist = new
     * Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MajorList.class);
     * majorlist.putExtra("type", getResources().getString(R.string.Education));
     * //startActivity(majorlist); break; case R.id.impn: majorlist = new
     * Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MajorList.class);
     * majorlist.putExtra("type", getResources().getString(R.string.Phn));
     * //startActivity(majorlist); break;
     *
     * }
     *
     * //replaceContentView("MajorList", majorlist); Group group =
     * (Group)getParent(); group.startChildActivity("MajorList", majorlist);
     *
     *
     * View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("Sales",
     * majorlist.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView();
     *
     * // replaceView(view);
     *
     * }
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Group group = (Group) getParent();
        group.onBackPressed();
        homelayout.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }

    private void Check()
    {
        if (settings.getString("lang", "en").equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
        {
            editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("lang", "el");
            editor.commit();
            Language_check(this, "el");
        }
        else
        {
            editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("lang", "en");
            editor.commit();
            Language_check(this, "en");
        }
        /*
         * if(getResources().getString(R.string.locale).equals("en")) { // Call
         * above method with context & newLocale Language_check(this, "el");
         * editor=settings.edit(); //editor.putString("lang", "") }else{ // Call
         * above method with context & newLocale Language_check(this, "en"); }
         */
    }

    private void Language_check(Context context, String string)
    {
        Locale locale2 = new Locale(string);
        Locale.setDefault(locale2);
        Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
        config2.locale = locale2;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Group group = (Group) getParent();
        // setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);

        // db.getcityDetails().getDatabase().
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LayoutTabAct.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        group.startActivity(i);
        group.onBackPressed();
        finish();

        // ** THIS IS BAD!! **
        System.gc();

        // this.destroyActivity();
        // Intent Start = new Intent("com.tg.sam.LayoutTabAct");
        // startActivity(Start);

        // finish();
        // setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
        // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
    {
        // startActivity(majorlist);

        if (arg2 == 9)
        {
            majorlist = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), PhoneList.class);
            majorlist.putExtra("type", categories[arg2]);
        }
        else
        {
            // replaceContentView("MajorList", majorlist);
            majorlist = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MajorList.class);
            majorlist.putExtra("type", categories[arg2]);
        }
        Group group = (Group) getParent();
        group.startChildActivity("MajorList", majorlist);
        // }
    }

    /*
     * public void replaceView(View v) { history.add(v); setContentView(v);
     *
     * }
     *
     * public void back() { if (history.size() > 0) {
     * history.remove(history.size() - 1); if (history.size() > 0) {
     * setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1)); } else { finish(); } }
     * else { finish(); } }
     *
     * public void backToFirst() { int size = history.size(); while (size > 1) {
     * history.remove(size - 1); size = history.size(); }
     * setContentView(history.get(0)); }
     *
     * @Override public void onBackPressed() { Home.group.back(); return; }
     */
}
```

**[EDIT 2]**

And, finially, this is your brand new **HomeAdapter.java**

```
package com.tg.sam;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

//import com.mycomics.sam.R;

public class HomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;
    private Integer[] images;

    public HomeAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues , Integer[] images)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
        this.images = images;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView = null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_mobile, null);

            // set value into textview

            /*if (mobile.equals("Accomodation")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.miaccomodation);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Food")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mifood);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Beaches")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mibeach);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Tourism")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mitourism);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Health")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mihealth);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Places")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.miplace);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Shopping")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mishopping);
            }else if (mobile.equals("Real Estate")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mirestate);
            }*/
        }
        else
        {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label2);
        textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

        // custom font for main categories
        String fontPath = "aus.ttf";
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPath);
        textView.setTypeface(tf);

        String mobile = mobileValues[position];
        textView.setText(mobile);

        // ** NO **
        // set image based on selected text
        // ** NO **
        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
        //  .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image2);
        //imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        final Drawable drw = 
            context.getResources().getDrawable(images[position]);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drw, null, null);

        return gridView;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return mobileValues.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This one is to be used with the TextView only version of **home_mobile.xml** (not the one you have put on DropBox).
Now you should have ALL. Test it now and let me know.

**[EDIT 3]**

I was finally able to make it work.
This is my result.
I didn't have all the resources, so I used what I had handy (note this is an emulated 2.8" ldpi screen, 240*320):

[image]