# Android : Advice to build this interface

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview

I would  like to reproduce this interface :

[image]

As you can see, each item of the list are in 2 column on each line.

How can i reproduce this ? With GridView ? Or a listview ?

Comment: I'd go for a **GridView**. Each item would be a TextView with a compound drawable on its top. I answered a very similar question some days ago. **Despite the title**, it's really that one: a dual column GridView with a TextView using a top compound drawable as GridView item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847672/qhd-and-800x480-different-layout-or-drawable-or-both/23848030#23848030

Comment: And it also has a **header** TextView with a compound drawable (you can use a TextView with a background image). So, it's **very similar to your design**.

Comment: Der Golem, in the example, the images have black circles with an item count and a rating symbol drawn on the picture. Extending ImageView and using OnDraw() would allow them to be dynamic. If this is desired, wouldn't using a RelativeLayout with custom ImageView class and a TextView for each Gridview item  be effective alternative to compound drawable?

Comment: @IslandWave: maybe you don't know that a single TextView can have MANY compound drawables (4) and that a compound drawable REDUCES the View count, which is OPTIMAL for PERFORMANCES (if you care about).

Comment: @Der Golem, I'm aware of compound drawables and performance but how to override OnDraw() method of an ImageView in a compound drawable? drawableTop, drawableBottom, drawableRight and drawableLeft all take a reference to another resource or a theme attribute. You can't draw on the ImageView unless you convert to Bitmap. Just saying.... as the Op's example has dymanic numbering drawn on the images. If he doesn't need dynamic images, compound drawable is fine but if he wants to "exactly" reproduce the example....

Comment: Well, that could just be another TextView with an xml drawable as its background an a number as its text. I used something similar to show the scores in a game (in a ListView as a container)